# Pass in user-specified parameters to query a database and return data

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am extremely new to Ruby on Rails, having only a couple days of experience. So far, I have created a new app, and loaded data into the database called name which is comprised of `date:string`, `value:decimal`, and `unique_id:integer`. So now, I can go to "(`my local port)/name`" and view the table successfully.

What I would like to do is this:

In a new html page, have a SIMILE Timeplot (http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/) with an HTML drop-down list below it in order to select a `unique_id` and another drop-down box to select a year.

From there, I would like to search through the database and display all of the data on the Timeplot that matches the `unique_id` and that is in the specified year.

I believe I must make an `HTTP GET` request for a `date_to`, `date_from`, and `unique_id`, but I do not know how to implement this (admittedly I have been searching the web for ages, but could not figure out the solution).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit: Even just advice on what component to tackle first

Comment: Try this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: You are welcome to present a concrete problem (which includes code samples), but as it is right now your question might be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a route for your search such as this:

```
match "name/search" to: "name#search" as: "name_search", via: :get
```

Then if you are using AJAX, and using jQuery you make an HTTP request like this:

```
$.get("/name/search", {
    unique_id: <your_unique_id>,
    date_from: <your_date_from>,
    date_to: <your_date_to> },
    function(result) {
        // You do whatever you want with the result here
    }
}
```

P.S:
The Javascript code might not be 100% correct, since I rarely use it.